# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have one short, but to me very important question!

I want this (using an .htaccess file):

> `http://localhost/riteh/view/buildings.php?p=1&r=10`

to look like:

> `http://localhost/riteh/view/buildings/1/10`

Could you please post the code that should be in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

presume your .htaccess is in http://locahost/ and p and r are both integers.

```
RewriteRule ^riteh/view/buildings/([0-1]+)/([0-1]+)/?$ riteh/view/buildings.php?p=$1&r=$2
```